# How can I download/upload multiple files at once using SFTP through the ssh2 Node.js module (within an Electron app)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ssh2-sftp, ssh2

I am building a simple SFTP client with Electron and I am attempting to download or upload multiple files at once using the ssh2 module and the SFTPStream within that module. I have tried many different method structures, some including use of es6-promise-pool. Every attempt I make results in one file from the array of files to transfer being transferred properly and then a subsequent

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 sftp_message listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

message is displayed in the console and the rest of the files are not transferred. I am unsure how to change my method structure to prevent this from occurring. I am using ipcRenderer to tell ipcMain to execute the methods I will display here (here is my structure for uploading files for example).

```
let counter = 0;

// Upload local file to server
ipcMain.on('upload_local_files', (event, args) => { // args[0] is connection settings, args[1] is array of file paths
  let conn = new Client();
  conn.on('ready', () => {
    let pool = new PromisePool(uploadFileProducer(conn, args[1]), 10);
    pool.start().then(() => {
      conn.end();
      counter = 0;
      let tempArgs = [];
      tempArgs.push(curLocalDir);
      tempArgs.push(curRemoteDir);
      event.sender.send('local_upload_complete', tempArgs);
    });
  }).connect(args[0]);
});

// Producer used in promise pool to upload files
function uploadFileProducer(conn, files){
  if(counter < 100 && counter < files.length){
    counter++;
    return(uploadFile(conn, files[counter - 1]));
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}

// Function used to upload files in promise pool
function uploadFile(conn, file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.sftp((error, sftp) => {
      return sftp.fastPut(file, curRemoteDir + file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), {}, (error) => {
        resolve(file);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Admittedly, the use of promise pools is new to me and I am unsure if I am going about using them properly. Another post about this topic used promise pools to prevent the problem I am having from occurring, but that example did not involve an Electron app (I don't know if that's relevant). I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Are you sure nothing is uploaded? Because that's just a warning, and it's a normal one if you're uploading several files at once.

Comment: Only the first file in the array is uploaded and that warning is given and then the connection is closed without uploading the rest of the files in the array

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with that, I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `Warning`, which is just that, a warning, and normal in your current use case. The issue with the uploads is the incorrect usage of `PromisePool`.

I'm assuming you're using [es6-promise-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool)

You should pass a promise producer function to the constructor, but instead you're calling the function and passing a promise, that's why only a single files gets uploaded.

You should pass the producer without calling it, or make a producer that returns a function, or use a generator.

> The PromisePool constructor takes a Promise-producing function as its
>   first argument.

```
function *uploadFileProducer(conn, files) {
    for(const file of files)
        yield uploadFile(conn, file);
}
```

Now you can call:

```
let pool = new PromisePool(uploadFileProducer(conn, args[1]), 10)
```

And the `PromisePool` will iterate correctly the iterator returned by the generator function, and handle the concurrency accordingly.

You can also create a function that returns a `Promise` each call.

```
function uploadFileProducer(conn, files) {
  files = files.slice(); // don't want to mutate the original
  return () => uploadFile(conn, files.shift())
}
```

---

Regarding the warning, it's normal if you're uploading multiple things concurrently, if that's the case you can increase the limit using:

```
emitter.setMaxListeners(n)
```